# How to fix wakelock issue on Samsung Galaxy S5 SM-G900H running Lollipop?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, wakelock, battery-history

I have a little problem with my Samsung Galaxy S5 SM-G900H from Orange Dominican Republic running Android 5.0.

It happens that suddenly the phone ots having wakelocks and I dont know what to do since I don't want to root the phone to know which one is the bad app.

Here are the screenshots  of the battery:

<sub>(Click to enlarge the image)</sub>

[stats after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6igR0.jpg)
[image: gsam stats]
[image: battery doctor stats]

After turn off remote controls
[image: remote controls off]

Battery stats
[image: stats after]

Location settings
[image: location]

Comment: Not an answer, but a pointer: check [these related questions](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=[battery]+android+system).

Answer (score 1):

- If you don't wanna root your phone there is no way of preventing the
  power consuming apps from doing so.
- From your screen shot I see the kernel and android system used most
  of your power but they are not the ones using power but there is apps
  on your phone are using core system functions so it's hard to say
  witch app is really using to much power.
- The other service using to much power is gpsd and I think it is the
  real problem here. gpsd is a gps [daemon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_%28computing%29) it's a piece of software that
  works with the gps sensor normally it shouldn't even appear in the
  battrie stat ,but samsung repaced it by it's own software to offer a remote location service for the phone to help users find their lost handset through a website, just as Apple does with Find My iPhone. Unfortunately it appears to be causing the GPS Daemon to continually search and update your phone’s position, thus running down the battery.  While it’s a useful feature, you’ll need to deactivate it for now to save your battery and hope that Samsung issues a fix for it soon. Here’s how to do it: if you need this service even with the expense of power you can keep it but if you don't want it follow the next steps to disable it.

  1. Open Settings
  2. search for Security and tap on it.
  3. Scroll down, tap Remote controls
  4. Enter the password for your Samsung account, tap OK in top right
  5. Slide the switch in the top right corner towards the left, where it
     should change to grey or off.

Comment: +1 for the answer.  Im testing now with just the bluetooth off and gps.  Then I will test what you suggest.  Thanks

Comment: There is the gpsd still there and it appears  to be wasting battery life.

Comment: @Jhonnytunes did you disable the feature as I suggested ?

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of the location under settings ? It has a list of apps using the localization feature

Comment: The feature is off as is the bluetooth and gps.

Comment: are you you using any apps that tracks your location like some fit apps ?

Comment: I had Airdroid which I also uninstalled

Comment: I am doing more research and I will be back as soon as I find something

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25768/discussion-between-jhonnytunes-and-lord-ralf-adolf).

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. These applications updated yesterday and I no longer have the wakelock problem unless I activate the Samsung remote controls.

Apps that updated:

- Amazon Shopping
- Drastic DS Emulator
- Evernote
- Google
- Google Keep
- Google Photos
- IMDB
- Juice SSH
- Google Maps
- Netflix
- Skype
- OOKLA Speedtest

[image]